# Copy sheet containing pivot tables and graphs with Phpexcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have to create an Excel file with a data sheet that will vary according to a database and **a sheet containing multiple PivotTables that have their own PivotCharts**.
Having already my sheet containing my PivotTables and PivotCharts.
I would just like to automate the action of "*copy a sheet on another workbook*".

First, I'm just trying to duplicate my file containing the sheet with the TCD and GCD.

that's my piece of code :

```
    $objPHPExcel1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("example.xlsx");
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel1, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('example2.xlsx');
```

This will create the file "example2.xlsx" but he will be empty with a single sheet instead of two.

Thanks to your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPExcel doesn't support pivot tables.

You'll have to use [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) (with MS Excel itself) or [Ilia Alshanetsky's Excel extension](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel) (with [libXL](http://www.libxl.com/)).

Comment: Thanks for your informations.
I don't understand how the COM class could work to open my excel file and to copy it.

Comment: The COM class is able to open an instance of MS Excel itself (assuming that you have it installed) and manipulate it under program control

Comment: @MarkBaker I cannot get how to use php_excel extension for this task. There are no docs. Please check my email sent to the address from github.